# Can not navigate to another screen with navigation.navigate

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a class Login with a function:

```
  async _logInWithFacebook() {
    await Facebook.initializeAsync(fbConfig.APP_ID);
    const { type, token } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(
      fbConfig.APP_ID,
      {
        permissions: ["public-profile", "email"],
      }
    );
    if (type === "success") {
      this.props.login(token, "facebook");
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
    } else {
      throw new Error("Something wrong with facebook auth");
    }
  }
```

I call it when I press a button log-in. Also I have a class HomeScreen, where I want to move after pressing the button.

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchMyMeetups();
  }
  render() {
    const {
      myMeetups: { isFetched, data, error },
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={styles.root}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <View style={styles.add}>
            <CreateMeetupScreen />
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.topContainer}>
          <Text>HomeScreen</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.bottomContainer}>
          <MyMeetupsList meetups={data} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default HomeScreen;
```

And my Navigator:

```
export function Navigator() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

So When I press the button I get an error:[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ref.navigation')]

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning , console log your props in every Component and check do you get your navigation on it or not, then dont forget to pass your Props you wanna pass to next screen as the second item of navigate function like

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Home",{SOME PROPS HERE});
```

then you will be able to get it in the next page and use it .
I hope it helps <3